# Homebrew can't install packages

Tags: macos, homebrew

I uninstalled homebrew to do a clean install using the method listed on the homebrew website but now I'm having issues with installing packages.

When I try a simple install of wget using:
`brew install wget`
I get this error message: 
[image: install]

Tried to run it as superuser but that gives the following error: 
[image: sudo install]
Thanks in advance!

---

Still can't install anything. Tried to install wget (and openssl is also installed with it) and got this: screenshot. Similar error when trying to install osxfuse
[image: Permission denied]

Comment: The Homebrew assumes you're installing on Linux, and the Mac OS X isn't well tested. I happened to use Kornshell and I had to munge these scripts to get it to work. Make sure you're installing Perlbrew as yourself, and in your HOME directory. This is installing in the System's `/Library` directory and not `$HOME/Library`. Make sure your shell is BASH and that `$HOME` is defined.

Comment: I was trying to look through my notes. My problem is that I use Kornshell by default and not BASH. If your default shell is BASH, and you have Xcode installed, and you have the command line tools, it should be fairly smooth. See [Installing Perl on OS X](http://learn.perl.org/installing/osx.html) for more information

Comment: Please put the code in the question not in links that might disappear

Comment: @DavidW., Homebrew is a package manager for OS X, not Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may have originally installed Homebrew with a different user id.

Try resetting the Homebrew cache permissions with:

```
sudo chown -R $USER $(brew --cache)
```

Comment: ***NOOOOO!*** This is the _system's_ Library directory. It should never have the permissions changed to a particular user. Doing so will cause issues on your Mac. ***DO NOT CHANGE THE PERMISSIONS IN `/Library`***. What should be going on is that Perlbrew should be installing itself in `$HOME/Library`.

Comment: @DavidW This question is about [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).  It expects the Cache folder to be owned by the brewing user profile.

Comment: One should never touch the permissions of files or directories under `/Library`. These files are for all _users_ on your system including the special users. Changing the ownership could prevent processes from being able to write to this directory. Perlbrew does install on MacOS X, but it sometimes takes a few tweaks. You need to us BASH, you need OS X, and you may need to make sure that your environment is okay.

Comment: @DavidW.: It's standard for Homebrew to be installed with a "normal" user, and that user needs to own Homebrew's cache directory. The directory pointed to by `brew --cache` should be owned by an admin user, and the group should be set to admin. This shouldn't cause problems since no other application should be using that directory anyway.

Comment: Still can't install anything. Tried to install wget (and openssl is also installed with it) and got this: [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/23xbgxl4jwulu80/Screenshot%202014-03-11%2010.10.55.jpg). Similar error when trying to install osxfuse

Comment: @Thibmaekelbergh `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/*` should fix it right up.